# trim namefield from right in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, substring

How can I trim a namefield from right and have only last n Characters.

I only found examples from left. I have the following SOQL where I tried this:

```
[select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :ids &&  Name.subString(Name.length() - 7, Name.length()) !='log.pdf']
```

I get the error :

> unexpected token: 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Name.length()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might this work for you?

```
SELECT Name, Body, BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN :ids AND (NOT Name LIKE '%log.pdf')
```

I'm assuming ids is a list or a set and not a single id? If it is a single id than it should be

```
SELECT Name, Body, BodyLength FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :ids AND (NOT Name LIKE '%log.pdf')
```

Comment: I ger the error: unexpected token: 'NOT'

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Try it now. (I forgot the () around not...)

Comment: Your welcome :)